# Filemaker Using a Repeating Field in A Portal to Display Related Records

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to modify a calendar module I use regularly and make it an image gallery.  I have a field in "Calendar Display Rows" called "display_images".  The display images field is a repeating numeric field that generates a number grid ([7] repetitions).

I have a repeating calculation field in "Calendar Display Rows" called "show images" ([7] repetitions) that is an unstored container field calculation that points at the "image" field in the table "Images".

Match fields are as follows:

Calendar Display Rows : display_images = Images : image number

How can I get the images in the "Images" table that have the matching image number to display dynamically in the repeating field "show images" according the matching number.

Note that I am trying to modify a calendar module because I want to resize the grid cleanly for a full screen appearance.  Horizontal portals will not work.  This is a vertical portal with a repeating field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Basics:

Your relationship:

```
Calendar Display Rows::display_images = Images::image number
```

will, from a layout showing Calendar Display Rows, find all the images with an `image number` matching the value in any of the repetitions of `display_images`. For instance, if display_images[1] = 1 and display_images[2] = 2, you'll get images 1 and 2 through the relationship *in whatever sort order is established for the relationship.*

Presuming that the repetitions of display_images are populated in the same order as your relationship's sort order, and that the only blank repetitions you have are at the highest end of the repetitions of the field (1, 2, 3, [blank] is okay, but 1, [blank], 3, 4 is not), you could use the following calculation for `Calendar Display Rows::show images`:

```
GetNthRecord (
   Extend ( Images::image ) ;
   Get ( CalculationRepetitionNumber )
)
```

In the above, `GetNthRecord` gets the nth record, by the sort order, of the related records in Images. `Extend` allows the related image to be used by any of the repetitions in the repeating `show images` field and `Get ( CalculationRepetitionNumber )` tells FileMaker that repetition 1 gets value 1, repetition 2 gets value 2, etc.

### More Advanced:

The assumptions above (matching sort order, no blank fields in the middle) would probably work for a calendar, but may not work for an image gallery. It's entirely possible that you'd need something that allowed for blank fields or mismatched sort order.

For that, a custom function (if you have FileMaker Advanced) may be in order. The function could repeat through the found Images records and test that display_images[i] matches image number.

`Find Proper Image` Custom Function:

```
Let (
      targetImageIndex = GetRepetition ( Calendar Display Rows::display_images ; forRepetition )
;
      Case (
           IsEmpty ( targetImageIndex ) ; "" ;
           workingRecord > Count ( Images::image number ) ; "" ;
           targetImageIndex = GetNthRecord ( Extend ( Images::image number ) ; workingRecord ) ; GetNthRecord ( Extend ( Images::image ) ; workingRecord ) ;
           Find Proper Image ( forRepetition ; workingRecord + 1 )
      )
)
```

Then the code in the `show images` calculation field would be:

```
Find Proper Image ( Get ( CalculationRepetitionNumber ) ; 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks @pft221 GetNthRecord ( Extend(Images::IMAGE) ; Get ( CalculationRepetitionNumber ) ) worked perfectly for the image grid!  Any thoughts on how I can get the corresponding imageID (serial number) from the related table in a script?

Comment: FYI I tried the same calculation to retrieve the ID but instead of returning unique ids in all rows of the portal it only returns 7 unique IDs and repeats the same row ids in all 6 rows of the portal.

Comment: NVM I got the calculation to work to display the ID.  This portal is buggy for some reason.  But do you have any thoughts on capturing the ID on click (setting a global variable) so that it can be used in a script?

Comment: It's probably worth another question--I rarely use repeating fields, so you might get a better answer on good UI for clicking repeating fields from someone else--but I would look at either invisible buttons on top of the repeating field or a script trigger that uses `Get(ActiveRepetitionNumber)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @pft221.  I was really hoping they would roll out a native horizontal portal in FMP13.